# How can I make a closure to conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swift-protocols

I created a view which displays a stack of cards. I am passing two parameters to it:

- an array of card data
- a closure that builds a CardView for each of the cards:

```swift
struct CardStack: View {
    var cards: [Card]
    var content: (Int, Card) -> CardView

    init(cards: [Card], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int, Card) -> CardView) {
        self.cards = cards
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(Array(cards.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, card in
                content(index, card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when the closure contains just the CardView, but as soon as I add any view modifier to the CardView (and I need to add many of them), the returned type of the closure changes to `some View`, and I get an error: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'some View' to return type 'CardView'`

```swift
var deckBody: some View {
    CardStack(cards: viewModel.cards) { index, card in  // Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'some View' to return type 'CardView'
        CardView(card: card)
            .zIndex(Double(index))
    }
}
```

Then, when I amend CardView to expect a closure returning `any View` instead of the `CardView`, I get another error `Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'`:

```swift
struct CardStack: View {
    var cards: [Card]
    var content: (Int, Card) -> any View

    init(cards: [Card], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int, Card) -> any View) {
        self.cards = cards
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(Array(cards.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, card in
                content(index, card)     // Error: Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why should I, and how can I make the closure conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CardStack` should have a generic type parameter indicating the type of `View` that each card is displayed as.

```
struct CardStack<CardContent: View>: View {
    var cards: [Card]
    var content: (Int, Card) -> CardContent

    init(cards: [Card], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int, Card) -> CardContent) {
        self.cards = cards
        self.content = content
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper! The generic type parameter solved the issue (I am pretty sure I tried it before, but I am not sure at all why it did not work ;) )